# Can we access historical data stored in druid

Tags: node.js, api, devops, druid

Assuming if we are storing historical data in Apache Druid can we from nodejs access them, including filtering, searching ..etc
Is there any api in druid so that we can write rest api's like we write for mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yes Apache Druid supports a REST API interface to almost all functions, including firing off ingestion jobs, monitoring, querying, etc.

Here's the docs on the subject:

General API reference for all services:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/api-reference.html

You'll be particularly interested in the Router API which allows you to submit Queries:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/api-reference.html#queries

SQL API:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#client-apis